# How to loop through the nested data in JSON while Processing with Jackson and Map

Tags: java, json, collections, jackson

I am parsing a **JSON** file with the following structure using **Jackson**.

**JOSN Structure:**

```
{
    "lang": "en",
    "data": {
        "USER_COMPONENT": {
            "USER_LABEL": "Users",
            "ADD_USER_LABEL": "Add new user",
            "USER_NAME": "Name",
            "NICK_NAME": "Nick Name",
            "USER_POSITION": "Position",
            "SEARCH_USER": "Search user",
            "ADMINISTRATOR_LABEL": "Administrator",
            "FIRST_NAME_LABEL": "First Name",
            "LAST_NAME_LABEL": "Last Name",
            "TEAM_LABEL": "Team",
            "POSITION_LABEL": "Position",

        },
        "USER_ACCESS_CONTROL": {
            "USER_ACCESS_CONTROL_LABEL": "User Access Control"
        }, ....
     }
  }
```

I am trying to parse the JSON data, get the **key-value** data, and store it in my DB. *Key*, *value*, and *array-name* are columns in the DB.

**Model Class:**

```
/**
 * LANGUAGE = "lang field in JSON"
 * SK = Generated by a function which combines LANGUAGE,COMPONENT_NAME,KEY.
 * COMPONENT_NAME = Array name is JSON eg: USER_COMPONENT.
 * KEY = Key value eg: USER_LABEL.
 * VALUE = Value of the KEY**/

    public class LanguageItem {
    
        private String LANGUAGE;
        private String SK;
        private String COMPONENT_NAME;
        private String KEY;
        private String VALUE;
    
        public LanguageItem() {
        }
    
        public LanguageItem(String language, String sk, String component_name, String key, String value) {
            LANGUAGE = language;
            SK = sk;
            COMPONENT_NAME = component_name;
            KEY = key;
            VALUE = value;
        }
        //.........
    }
```

I am creating an **ArrayList** of **LanguageItem**.

```
ArrayList<LanguageItem> languageItemList = new ArrayList<LanguageItem>();
```

So I have to loop through the JSON data and create the **LanguageItem** and add to the **languageItemList**.

All the *keys* and *array names* will be **unique**.
This means I can't use a method like is `map.get("USER_LABEL");` because there will be 100s of key-value pairs and arrays.

I have tried to parse this JSON, using **Map**.

**With Map:**

```
public void storeJsonToMap(List<MultipartFile> file) throws IOException {

    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

    Map<String, Object> langMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    langMap = objectMapper.readValue(file.get(0).getBytes(), Map.class);

    for (Map.Entry entry : langMap.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println("\n----langMap-\n" + entry.getKey() + "=" + entry.getValue());
    }
}
```

**Log Output:**
[image]

The issue facing with Map is that I can get the items ***lang*** and ***data*** (from the JSON data). Since **entry** is not an array how to loop through the ***data*** and get the value of both **key & value?**

Comment: Can you please make your question a little more understandable? I think an example of input and expected output will be a good start

Comment: @BuildSlayer I have added the Input. Output, that's something I cannot illustrate. But I have explained it. I will edit and add more info

Comment: @BuildSlayer Edited.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get value from entry with key `data` and then fetch user data from it.

```
    for (Map.Entry entry : langMap.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println("\n----langMap-\n" + entry.getKey() + "=" + entry.getValue());
        if(entry.getKey().equals("data")) {
            System.out.println(((Map<String, Object>)entry.getValue()).get("USER_COMPONENT"));
            System.out.println(((Map<String, Object>)entry.getValue()).get("USER_ACCESS_CONTROL"));

            // OR
            Map<String, Object> userComponentMap = objectMapper.convertValue(entry.getValue(), new TypeReference<>() {});
            System.out.println(userComponentMap.get("USER_COMPONENT"));
            System.out.println(userComponentMap.get("USER_ACCESS_CONTROL"));
        }
    }
```

Also if you just want `data` element and ignore other elements, then you can fetch it without iterating over map entries.

```
    Map<String, Object> dataMap = (Map<String, Object>) langMap.get("data");
    // OR
    // Map<String, Object> dataMap = objectMapper.convertValue(langMap.get("data"), new TypeReference<>() {});

    System.out.println(dataMap.get("USER_COMPONENT"));
    System.out.println(dataMap.get("USER_ACCESS_CONTROL"));
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I can't specify the key as a String. Like I said in the question. The Key is unique. which means there will be 100's of pairs of attributes with different keys.  I need a solution that doesn't use a key. instead loops through the data. and fetch key and value

Answer (score 0):

```
     try {
        Object obj = new JSONParser().parse(newFileReader("filename.json"));
        JSONObject jo = (JSONObject) obj;
        Map data = ((Map) jo.get("data"));
        Iterator<Map.Entry> itr1 = data.entrySet().iterator();

        while (itr1.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry pair = itr1.next();
            System.out.println(pair.getKey() + " : " + pair.getValue());
            // List<Object> val = (List<Object>) pair.getValue();
            JSONObject objs = (JSONObject) pair.getValue();
            objs.keySet().forEach(keyStr -> {
                Object keyvalue = objs.get(keyStr);
                System.out.println("key: " + keyStr + " value: " + keyvalue);
            });
        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (org.json.simple.parser.ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```